# Format ms Access Graph programmatically

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is there any way to alter the format of a graph in a Microsoft Access report programmatically?
I know my way around the automation of a report, I just don't know how to access the properties of an axis (or whatever) of a graph to change them.

Comment: Do you know how to access the properties of any object in VBA?

Comment: Yes, but I don't see any of the chart object's properties other than the ones exposed though access.  I can set things like row source, but not internal things like scale, data labels, or fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Charting in access is almost the same as in excel. So if you need to know something record a macro in excel and you will see the code.

This is the best one can do while ever you are not showing code.

Comment: Awesome tip, it works perfectly to expose the properties of the graph. thanks.